# How to build a stereoscopic viewer of a photosphere image using Google Cardboard SDK

Tags: android, google-cardboard, stereoscopy, photosphere

The Cardboard Demo app has a good feature where we can see existing photospheres. I want to build a similar application

I've gone through [Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/overview) that google has provided. But haven't found an easy way to do it. I've to build from scratch literally, taking all the sensory inputs and updating frames accordingly which is a very pain taking process.

I want to know

1. If there is an easy way to do it
2. If there is source code of Google Cardboard app available that I can build on

Comment: Use unity and Cardboard SDK for Unity. Unless you earned over 100k USD last year, you can use it for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Rajawali Framework with RajawaliVR or just use this example : 
https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

[Google Cardboard 360 degree view](https://github.com/pollux-/GoogleCardBoardVr-360-PhotoSphere)

Answer (score 0):

A. Install your Unity Pro with Android Pro plugins, setup Cardboard SDK For Unity, install Android Build tools and SDK.

B. Setup Skybox

1. Get a stereoscopic panorama image.
   In Unity, import the image, change the Texture Type to Cubemap.
2. Select the Mapping as Cylindrical (Lat and Long).
3. Create a Material, change the Shader to Skybox/Cubemap.
4. Assign the texture to the material.
5. In Unity 5 Pro topbar, select Window -> Lighthing, drag the material to the Skybox property.
6. Combine these steps with the Cardboard assets and game objects.

**The whole setup is just take out your five minutes(excluding setup your tools :D). You can refer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821239/1371949).**