# Apply Cardboard distortion to stereoscopic image

Tags: google-cardboard, stereoscopy, vrone

I would like to write an App that displays stereoscopic images on a Zeiss VR one. Currently I am simply displaying the images side by side, but they seem a little distorted. Is there a way to apply the barrel distortion used in the cardboard apps to a view?

Comment: What build tools are you using? Unity + Cardboard SDK?

Comment: I was only using the Android build tools, now I moved to Unity and Cardboard since I was not able to apply the distortion.

Comment: You could try using Android + Cardboard SDK. The distortion thingie is involved with bunch of calculations. It's handled by Cardboard SDK itself and you need to just "tick" to use. Maybe you can start with my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30821239/1371949